# Run batch command after ant build

Tags: ant, command-line, batch-file, callback

I'm trying to create a batch file that automates an annoying build process. The key part that's tripping me up is when a command starts a process that takes over input from the keyboard.

Basically, I run something along the lines of ant -f build-rmi.xml rmiregistry, which builds and runs the rmiregistry. After this is completed i need to run another build, but I can't figure out how to launch another command after the ant build is finished executing

I don't have write access to any of the ant files.

Comment: What if you try "ant -f build-rmi.xml rmiregistry && your command"?

Comment: Depends on what OS you are running in. Can you create a script file?

Comment: Did you try creating a batch file, putting `ant -f build-rmi.xml rmiregistry` in the first line, and another command in the next line?

Comment: Why you need to write a batch file (or anything that is OS dependent), when you could create an Ant build file and just put two `<ant>` tasks in a target...

Comment: @Pulak actually I mentioned that I don't have write access to the original files. So coolcfan's solution of creating a new ant build file is more correct.

Comment: @coolcfan It doesn't work. It still ends with rmiregistry seemingly waiting for input

Comment: @Matt my bad.. I've edited my answer. Have you tried this already ?

Comment: @MattSevrens That is to say, target `rmiregistry` will not end unless it gets some input? Which kind of input - a particular word or else? Check build-rmi.xml to see which part causes that waiting for input, and put that part in your question if possible, which helps people to understand your problem better.

Comment: This is the target being called:

`code`
<target name="rmiregistry">
    <exec executable="rmiregistry">
        <env key="CLASSPATH" path="somejar; anotherjar; anotherotherjar"/>
    </exec>
</target>
`code`

It's not really expecting any input. It's just capitalizing the command prompt and no new commands can be issued.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new ANT build script **run-both.xml**
2. Add an Import in **run-both.xml** to get the original script.
3. Create a new target in **run-both.xml**, say "runbatch".Use [ANT exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) to call the DOS command from this target

> ```
> <project name="run-both" default="runbatch"> 
> <import file="${path_to_rmi}/build-rmi.xml"/> 
>
> <target name="runbatch" depends="rmiregistry">   
>     <exec executable="cmd">
>        <arg value="/c"/>
>        <arg value="echo hello Matt"/>   
>     </exec>
>  </target>
> </project>
> ```

On the command prompt

`ant -f run-both.xml`

Comment: Same problem. The interesting thing is, if rmiregistry is already running, the execution will continue onto the next target. If it's not it just stops and capitalizes the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

use command call , the batch script file will not stop after run ant command

```
 call ant
```